# Extern variable not declared

Tags: c++, publish-subscribe, extern, ros

I am trying to pass a variable from the main.cpp to message.cpp.

My situation is basically this (removing the unrelated parts of code):

**main.cpp**

```
extern ros::Publisher pub;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
    pub = nh.advertise<myws_ros::Message>("/myws_ros/message", 1000);

}
```

**message.cpp**

```
#include <main.cpp>
void onAction()
{ 
    //write message
    pub.publish(message)
}
```

It is not compiling with this error:

> error: ‘pub’ was not declared in this scope

I thought including main, where pub is an extern variable, it should be declared. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I thought including main, where pub is an extern variable, it should be declared." No, this is wrong on a fundamental level. I recommend a good beginner's book.

Comment: `#include <main.cpp>` in `message.cpp` is not a good idea. This (at least) duplicates the definition of `int main()`. (Once you fixed the pub issue you get probably a link error.)

Comment: There is no main.h currently, I read against creating it for the main function but I think it may be what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Including main.cpp from message.cpp is certainly wrong. You should just declare `pub` in one translation unit. Since it's defined `extern` is main.cpp, you can just declare it `ros::Publisher pub;` in message.cpp.

Comment: The program was working before creating the publisher in message.cpp (nodehandle and advertise), but now I need it to be created since I run the main, and just publish the messages when onAction.